# ImportError: DLL load failed (about netCDF4)

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10-desktop, netcdf4

I'm an anaconda3 beginner,

I want to install `netCDF4` on my windows 10, here some commands I typed:

```
conda install hdf5
conda install netcdf4
```

they all list in my `conda list`， but when I import `netCDF4`, it failed, it said:

> DLL load failed

Does anyone know what's wrong?

[ImportError: DLL load failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj4Em.jpg)

And I also try other commands

```
conda remove netcdf4
conda uninstall netcdf4
pip install netcdf4
```

It shows:

> command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2fymkcam\netcdf4\

[pip install netcdf4 failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkDRn.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: I just removed anaconda3, and install anacond2.  
 >"conda install hdf5" + "conda install netcdf4"
>"conda remove netcdf4"
>"conda install netcdf4" again
and it worked, i don't even know why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose ImportError: DLL load failed when loading native Windows python modules in a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352027/how-do-i-diagnose-importerror-dll-load-failed-when-loading-native-windows-pytho)