# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found after i download scipy for windows 64 using python 2.7

Tags: python, scipy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\D\MyNewProject\Sequential-RNN-Decoder-master\conv_codes_benchmark.py", line 5, in <module>

    from utils import corrupt_signal, get_test_sigmas
  File "C:\D\MyNewProject\Sequential-RNN-Decoder-master\utils.py", line 12, in <module>

    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>

    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 169, in <module>

    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>

    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have downloaded scipy for windows 64bit from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy got above errors

Comment: Did you install it using pip after you downloaded it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose ImportError: DLL load failed when loading native Windows python modules in a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352027/how-do-i-diagnose-importerror-dll-load-failed-when-loading-native-windows-pytho)

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you